# How to get Android Device Serial Number (on Android 10 API level 28) in UNITY Oculus Quest 2 and Vive Focus

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, oculus

I need **serial number or something that works similarly** because our company creates applications for VR and I create web API that must recognize a specific device in several applications, because we assign subscriptions to the customer per device.

`SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier` can't be because it generates a different id for each application.

**So far I have used this:**

```
AndroidJavaObject jo = new AndroidJavaObject("android.os.Build");
string serial = jo.GetStatic<string>("SERIAL");
return serial;
```

but on android 10 it stops working and for HTC VIVE Focus HMD this function does not work at all.

Perfectly, I would use some id that is invariant for a given device if it's possible. I also allow the use of some id that will be created for the user and removed when the device is reset to initial state.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a solution for this??